# Why is my code only returning "Exit status: 0"?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a script that will ask you what you want to spam and how many times
you want to spam it, but when i run it it only returns "Exit status: 0". I can't figure out why its not working the right way. The script is "supposed to" first asks you what you want to spam then hwo many times to spam that word(s). After that it should ask you if you want to proceed. If you answer with "Y" then it should wait 5 sec and then write the message and press enter as amny times as you wrote.
(sorry for my bad vocabulary and script, very new to coding and python)

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep 
from tqdm import tqdm


coolDOwn = 0
time = 0 

def spam(msg, maxMsg):
    count = 0
    while count != maxMsg:
        count += 1
        print("Send message: " + str(count))
        pyautogui.write(msg)
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        if count == 10 or count == 20 or count == 30 or count == 40 or count == 50 or count == 60 or count == 70 or count == 80 or count == 90:
            if count == maxMsg:
                print(
'''
  _____   ____  _   _ ______ 
 |  __ \ / __ \| \ | |  ____|
 | |  | | |  | |  \| | |__   
 | |  | | |  | | . ` |  __|  
 | |__| | |__| | |\  | |____ 
 |_____/ \____/|_| \_|______|
                             
                             

        '''
        )

sleep(5)

def setup():
    while time != 12:
        time += 1
        sleep(1)
        print("Spammer loading")
        print("Spammer loading.")
        print("Spammer loading..")
        print("Spammer loading...")
        print("Spammer loading")
        print("Spammer loading.")
        print("Spammer loading..")
        print("Spammer loading...")
        print("Spammer loading")
        print("Spammer loading.")
        print("Spammer loading..")
        print("Spammer loading...")
        print("Spammer loading")
        print("Spammer loading.")
        print("Spammer loading..")
        print("Spammer loading...")
        print("Spammer ready:")
        msg = str(input("What would you like to spam: "))
        if msg != (""):
            msgMax = int(input("How many times would you like to spam that? [1-100]: "))
        answer = str(input("Would you like to proceed. [Y/n]: "))
        answer0 = answer.upper()
        if answer0 == ("Y"):
            while coolDown != 5:
                coolDOwn += 1
                sleep(1)
                spam(msg, msgMax)
                stop = str(input("Exit? [Y/n]: "))
                stop0 = stop.upper()
                if stop0 == ("Y"):
                    exit()
                if stop0 == ("N"):
                    setup()
        elif answer0 == ("N"):
            exit()
```

Comment: Your code shows that you've *defined* two functions, but it doesn't show you calling them at all from the top level of your module. You probably need to do that (perhaps in an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block) if you want it to be run as a script.

Comment: Like what @Blcknght said you can call them using ```funcname()``` or in your case ```spam()``` and ```setup()``` after you define them

Comment: Thank you, will try it in the morning it’s midnight here so